# Android: No icon for Notification

Tags: android, user-interface, notifications, icons

I wanted to create a notification without the icon in the status bar (the state that is not expanded). I tried the custom expanded view and set the icon for this view only. But it did not work. When I give 0 as icon to the constructor, the icon disappears but notification also does not appear in the expanded view.

Notification notification = new Notification(0, "", 0);

I tried a lot of combinations but didn't come out with a solution. By the way, I know it is working because I saw this feature in some apps. Thanks.

Comment: If you show an empty notification bar, why would the user expand it?

Comment: the user will always know it is there to serve but will not be disturbed by the icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QuickSettings did this and as I looked at that code I saw it uses the default constructor of Notification and pushes its icon to the right of the notification bar. I think it still uses space but has no icon.

Some code:

```
notification = new Notification();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
long hiddenTime = Constants.SDK_VERSION >= 9 ? -Long.MAX_VALUE : Long.MAX_VALUE;
notification.when = visible ? System.currentTimeMillis() : hiddenTime; // align
// left (0) / right (max) in status bar
```

edit: oh sorry I missed an important line of code, in fact he uses a placeholder. But now you have some code ;-)

```
notification.icon = visible ? (status == Constants.STATUS_BLACK_ICON ? 
                            R.drawable.ic_logo_black : R.drawable.ic_logo_white)
                            : R.drawable.ic_placeholder;
```

http://code.google.com/p/quick-settings/source/browse/trunk/quick-settings/src/com/bwx/bequick/receivers/StatusBarIntegrationReceiver.java

Comment: a smart hack actually. Thanks :)

Comment: @ludwigm, QuickSettings code is not available anymore, can you elaborate a little bit more about the solution. I didn't fully understand how things really work.

Comment: Found the source code here - http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Tools/quick-settings/com/bwx/bequick/receivers/StatusBarIntegrationReceiver.java.htm

Comment: That is down too, found a copy here: https://github.com/yanchenko/quick-settings/blob/master/src/com/bwx/bequick/receivers/StatusBarIntegrationReceiver.java

Answer (score 25):

This is now possible in Android 4.1; the reference implementation of the Jelly Bean status bar will suppress icons for [PRIORITY_MIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN) notifications, although their content will still show in the notification panel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transparent images as the notification icon. but as molnarm already mentioned, the user won't notify that there is a new notification

Comment: This is not possible, even though you gave an icon in 1 pixel dimension. it reserves what it should be and displays it white.

Comment: I just don't want to reserve an area there. It is doesn't matter black, white or transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to experiment with.  Put up a notification twice, once with icon=0 and once with a real icon.  Try it in one order and then in the opposite order.

I got the effect of no notification in status bar and notification in expanded list when I did something like this, except that one of the two (the one with icon=0) was put up by Service.startForeground().  I don't have time to experiment more right now.