# Create notification without icon in status bar

Tags: android

Is it possible to create notification without changing it's priority but still not to have an icon in the status bar as long as the notification is alive?

I saw this suggestion: [Create a persistent notification and prevent notification in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205551/create-a-persistent-notification-and-prevent-notification-in-status-bar)

But it's not really helping since the icon is created, but it's transparent.

Thanks,
Gidi

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855110/android-no-icon-for-notification)

Comment: So you just want to show a notification without any startforegound() or icon in the status bar?

Comment: yes, i want to have the notification in the notification bar, but without persist icon on the status bar (since i already have one from previous notification)

Comment: Hi Steve, Sorry it took me a while to answer. I tried it and it seems it creates a transparent icon which leaves space and i don't want this.