# How to set the status notification icon in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I'm trying to create a notification without an icon.
As I understand the only "formal" option to do it is setting the priority of the notification to `minimum`, This option is for SDK 16 only and I don't want my notification to be with low priority.
The second option is using a transparent icon and push it as right as possible on the status bar.
I've seen this thread :
[Android: No icon for Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855110/android-no-icon-for-notification)
I've tried setting the `notificatio.when` to `Long.MAX` or `-Long.MAX` but it didn't seem to work. (tasker icon was always on the right).

Thanks !

Comment: "I'm trying to create a notification without an icon" -- I hope that this is impossible.

Comment: Why would you hope for that ?

Comment: Because it is inappropriate to try to hide a notification from the user. That's up there with operating the notebook camera with the light off.

Comment: And what if it's a request from a lot of the application users ?  Not everything is black and white. Constant notification icons aren't always welcome.

Comment: Then don't have a notification. Or, allow the user to configure whether you show a notification or not. Nobody is forcing you to have a notification; they are only forcing you to have an icon if you do elect to have a notification.

Comment: @CommonsWare , The app is actually only a notification.