# Showing text permanently in the notification bar

Tags: android

I'd like to ask how it is possible to show text permanently in the notification bar?
The ticker set by the `setTicker()` method disappears after a few seconds.

My goal is to show the current temperature in the notification bar. What would be the best solution to do this? Maybe there's a way to pass text to the `setSmallIcon()` method?

Here's my notification code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            notBuilder.setContentText("text");
            notBuilder.setContentTitle("title");
            notBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
            notBuilder.setTicker("ticker");
            notBuilder.setOngoing(true);
            int notID = 8;
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(notID, notBuilder.build());
```

(is there a better solution to hide the small icon? it's transparent this way but still takes up the place)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set this flag to your builder `notBuilder.setOngoing(true);`. This will show the notification permanently as far as icon is concerned set a small transparent image.

You can try `notBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: It is set, the notification stays permanent, but the text (set by the setTicker() method) still disappears. I want the text permanent, similar to the small icon.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to show a permanent icon in the status bar. The text set by the ticker can't be permanent and appears only for a period if the notification shows the first time. This is by design because the user usually don't want a permanent message which "hides" the status bar.

To hide the small icon completely you could use [NotificationBuilder.setPriority(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int)) with the flag [Notification.PRIORITY_MIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_MIN). This way the notification will be reduced to a minimum, which includes the hiding of the icon. But this method is only available in API 16+. Below this level you can set a transperent icon (what you already did), but the space for the icon acts like a placeholder and can't be deleted. Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855110/android-no-icon-for-notification) is helpful for your situation, but it just moves the icon space to another area.